# WPF: ArrangeOverride in Customized StackPanel

Tags: wpf, scroll, panel, stackpanel

I want to make a custom Panel to (amongst other things) insert spacing between all children. To inherit from Panel seemed very complicated and perhaps unnecessary. What I want is close to StackPanel so I figured I could inherit from StackPanel and modify the ArrangeOverride and MeasureOverride to get what I want.
I got the implementation of these from Reflector but immediately noticed that one property was not accessible at all from a inherited class, namely IsScrolling (and the field _scrollData). My question is if I can skip this or if there is any other way of implementing identical behaviour? Im not sure I will need scrolling for this custom panel but I may do some day and I dont want to paint myself into a corner...

Answer (score 0):

if all you want is just that all elements inside a container would automatically contain margin definitions, you're **much** better off just creating a custom behavior that implements that functionality.

to create a custom behavior, just implement `Behavior<Panel>`. It's rather self-explanatory, but if you don't know how then ask.

Comment: I want to add space between the children without using margin (they should be able to use other margins themselves as well), and I want to be able to specify a Fill-property to dock/fill the children according to some rules and I want to add a grouping-property to separate groups of children with a larger space etc. Can I do all this with a Behavior? It seems a custom Panel is more appropriate?

Comment: In this case, yeah, Custom Panel is the way to go. As to your question then - I think this is part of the IScrollInfo infrastructure, used to handle the ScrollViewer integration. I think you can ignore it if you don't need custom behavior when in comes to scrolling.

Comment: I'd second Elad, you really need a string reason to go custom panel route. It's always nice to rely on existing functionality.

For starters I'd suggest that Dock panel as a major UI element is more appropriate, due to the usage of Fill.

Margins can be done by including 'spacer' elements if you don't want to mess with elements margins. 
Grouping can be done by using stackpanels as children.

Could you send us an image of what it should look like?

Comment: I noticed DockPanel had a much simpler implementation than StackPanel. Ill create my custom panel by using DockPanel as a blueprint. Thanks for the tips...